# What is the equivalent code from urllib2 to urllib3 in python

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib3

I am new to coding and am following an online course. The example in the course uses urllib2. For some reason I can't get urllib2 but i have got urllib3. The code they have written is for urllib2 as shown below:

```py
webRequest = urllib2.Request(urlofFilename,headers=hdr)
```

When I write this out to do the same thing with urllib3 ie:

`webRequest = urllib3.Request(urlofFilename,headers=hdr)`

It gives me an error stating that the urllib3 module has no attribute 'Request'.

How then do i write the same bit of code but for urllib3?

Cheer

Comment: Try `urllib3.request` instead of `Request`

Comment: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html could help

Comment: urllib3 read the docs is not helpful what so ever. I've seen people posting this comment to other questions.

Comment: urllib3.request comes back with module not callable

Answer (score 2):

To instantiate a Request object in urllib3, you're supposed to use the [`PoolManager()`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html). You'll pass headers as additional [request data](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#request-data):

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
webRequest = http.request('GET', urlofFilename, headers={'key': value})
```

Comment: I tried this too. I tried it before i aske the original question. where you have headers=.... in my code the key value pair has been defined as hdr. so in my code headers=hdr.

Comment: however when i run it.... a whole load of stuff comes up. The last thing being  "location parse error".

Comment: "location parse error" sounds like `urllib3` has problems fetch the url you provided. Have you tried another url? Or maybe [this issue](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/38) is similar to yours?

Comment: Its probably to do something with the fact the url is the newyork stock exchange and they put a blocker on scripts trying to download automatically. however thats why the header is defined as hdr....hdr being a dictionary set up to get around the block, by defining the user agent, ie. pretending like it is actually me reqeusting as opposed to a script

Answer (score 0):

Urllib2 and Urllib3 has some changes.You can touch it by reading documentation.
Sample code is below.

This is a Urllib3 documentation [Urllib3-Documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('POST', 'https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html')
print(r.status)
```

- Advice : if you are starting something newly please go thru the original documentation. :|)